# Как дать юзеру www-data возможность создавать файлы в определенной папке?

Tags: php, linux, bash

собственно, вопрос в сабже. Я попробовал вот [это](https://toster.ru/q/313363), но это мне не помогло. Мне нужно запустить из php определенный bash скрипт на сервере, в котором, собственно, и создается файл. Как можно было бы такое реализовать?

Comment: @aleksandr ничего непонятного, я все сделал и скрипт теперь выполняется, но в процессе выполнения скрипта юзеру www-data не хватает прав на создание файла

Comment: @aleksandr скрипт полностью выполняется от рута. Но я тестирую всю систему через sudo, выполняя скрипт от имени www-data, и вот уже в этому случае не создается файл, пишет аксес денайд.

Comment: @aleksandr add_domain.sh не должен выполняться от рута. Он выполняется функцией exec()  из php-кода. Поэтому я все пытаюсь настроить под www-data

Comment: в приведённом примере вы пытаетесь (естественно, неудачно) выполнить скрипт `add_domain.sh` как раз от имени пользователя root. вероятно, ввиду того, что внутри скрипта выполняются какие-то административные действия. если это не является вашей целью, как следует из последнего коммантария, то я умолкаю (в абсолютном непонимании — что же вам на самом деле нужно). удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Как решить эту проблему более вменяемо, нежели давать www-data рутовый доступ или сомнительные 777 права на папку.

Существует такая штука как [ACL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)). 
По ссылке вы можете прочитать или возможно даже вы с этим знакомы, но не знаете как применить на практике.

В трех словах, вы можете минуя манипуляции с группами и пользователями, сделать любой доступ нужного пользователя к любой папке (на счет любой папки это не точно :) )

Теперь ближе к делу. Если у вас не установлен acl - установите. Посмотрите как это делается конкретно для вашего дистрибутива.

А дальше происходит магия (посмотрите как это делается для Symfony [тут](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html) )

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
```

В трех словах что тут происходит. Вы в переменную HTTPDUSER записываете имя пользователя от которого запущен ваш веб сервер. В вашем случае это будет www-data, а далее же с помощью acl а конкретно команда `setfacl` назначаете нужные вам права на папку. В это случае это папка var, вы пишете нужную вам папку.

Ну и тут еще присутствует `$(whoami)` что в баше возвращает имя текущего пользователя (вы ведь не под рутом работаете, правда же ? )

Собственно как работает setfacl в подробностях вы можете посмотреть почитав на нее документацию.